# Assets missing/not compiling on Elastic Beanstalk after Configuration Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My rails application deploys and compiles assets as expected after a new deployment of code to elastic beanstalk.
However, if I change an environment variable within the elastic beanstalk 'software' section, the application is updated: `Updating environment <myapp> configuration settings.`, but the assets are not found.

Elastic beanstalk appears to be creating the rails app in the existing instances in a `/var/app/staging` folder and swapping it out to `/var/app/current`, but never runs the asset compile tasks.

I believe I'm using as standard a rails setup as possible, and have my env vars setup correctly:

```
RAILS_SKIP_MIGRATIONS: false
RAILS_SKIP_ASSET_COMPILATION: false
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried running the app in production mode locally with the environment variables added?

Comment: The app builds fine locally. I wouldn't know what's happening internally when an Amazon configuration change happens, so I can't simulate it locally unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion though 

Comment: I'm trying this now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62600427/elastic-beanstalk-is-causing-my-rails-6-app-precompiled-assets-to-break-when-add#comment113667327_64261296

Comment: Is the issue solved @Alan?